# LOAD DATA INFILE selectively with external file

Tags: mysql, linux, unix, find

I have a file called `/tmp/files.txt` in the following structure:

```
652083        8 -rw-r--r--    1 david            staff                1055 Mar 15  2012 ./Highstock-1.1.5/examples/scrollbar-disabled/index.htm
652088        0 drwxr-xr-x    3 david            staff                 102 May 31  2012 ./Highstock-1.1.5/examples/spline
652089        8 -rw-r--r--    1 david            staff                1087 Mar 15  2012 ./Highstock-1.1.5/examples/spline/index.htm
652074        0 drwxr-xr-x    3 david            staff                 102 May 31  2012 ./Highstock-1.1.5/examples/step-line
652075        8 -rw-r--r--    1 david            staff                1103 Mar 15  2012 ./Highstock-1.1.5/examples/step-line/index.htm
```

I want to insert the filename (col 9), filesize (col 7), and last_modified (col 8)into a mysql  table, `paths`.

To insert the entire line, I can do something like:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '/tmp/files.txt' INTO TABLE path
```

How would I selectively insert the required information into the necessary columns here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify dummy MySQL user variables (e.g. @dummy1) as the target for the unwanted values.

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '/tmp/files.txt'
INTO TABLE path 
(@d1, @d2, @d3, @d4, @d5, @d6, filesize, @mon, @day, @ccyy_or_hhmi, filename)
SET last_modified = CONCAT(@mon,' ',@day,' ',@ccyy_or_hhmi)
```

With that, the first six values from the input line are ignored (the values are assigned to the specified user variables, which we disregard.)  The seventh value gets assigned to the `filesize` column, the eighth through tenth values (the month day and year/time are assigned to user variables, and then the eleventh value is assigned to the `filename` column.

Finally, we use an expression to concatenate the month, day and year/time values together, and assign it to the `last_modified` column.  (NOTE: the resulting string is not guaranteed to be suitable for assigning to a DATE or DATETIME column, since that last value can either be a year, or it can be a time.)

(I've made the assumption that table `path` has columns named filesize, last_modified, and filename, and that there aren't other other columns in the table that need to be set.)

---

### Followup

If the data to be loaded is the output of a find command, I would be tempted to use the `-printf` action of find, rather than `-ls`, so I would have control over the output produced. For example:

```
find . -type f -printf "%b\t%TY-%Tm-%Td %TH:%TM\t%p\n" >/tmp/myfiles.txt
```

That would give you three fields, separated by tabs:

```
size_in_blocks   modified_yyyy_mm_dd_hh_mi  filename
```

That would be very easy to load into a MySQL table:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '/tmp/myfiles.txt'
INTO TABLE path
(filesize, last_modified, filename)
```

Comment: Thanks, though when using the above it gives me an entirely empty output. The file I have is the pipe from `'find . -ls'`.

Comment: It seems it is not separating on the tabs/spaces that is used in the ls command.

Comment: @David542: as one option, you could convert the whitespace to tabs. One way would to do that would be pipe the output trough a `tr -s ' ' | tr ' ' '\t'` before it's read by the MySQL LOAD DATA statement. An even better option, if you have control over that find command, would be to use the -printf action rather than the -ls action, so you can specify the format of the output produced. (Followup added to answer above.)

Comment: Thanks for the updated answer, though unfortunately I'm on a mac, and it doesn't recognize the `-printf` option in the find command.